# how do get last row value from a dynamic data table in selenium webdriver....any solution

Tags: java, selenium, datatable

In my current working application have a data table its store the history of my work activities. During the run time of scripts through selenium web driver( Java), at that table it increase one row . Now for validation purpose I need to get that new row data.
How can I get that anyone has any solution?

Comment: Provide relevant HTML for the same.

Comment: Without Html no one can help

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(locator, number));
```

300 is time in milliseconds